# Error when Exporting Site to Agency

Tags: sxa, creative-exchange

We are using Sitecore 9.0.2 with SXA 1.7.1 and we have an exception when exporting the site for the Front-End using creative exchange
[image]

any Advice?

Comment: Check `Start item` field on your site definition item (`/sitecore/content/T/S/Settings/Site Grouping/S`). It should not be empty.

Comment: it's the same as the tenants homepage

Comment: it should point to the start item of your site. By default it is `/sitecore/content/T/S/Home`

Comment: this is the value for it

Comment: Do you have any wildcard items in your site?